# Remote kubernetes server unreachable

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to install kubernetes with Docker desktop. However, as soon as I type in

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I get Remote kubernetes server unreachable error.

```
I0217 23:42:56.224000   26220 versioner.go:56] Remote kubernetes server unreachable
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.28.112.98:6443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you abel to ping 172.28.112.98 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Have you got more than one context? Check with "kubectl config get-contexts". If necessary change context using "kubectl config use-context docker-desktop"

Comment: @RobinWebb That did it for me. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @RobinWebb can you put your solution in an answer so it is more accessible to the community?

Comment: Added to solution as requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you got more than one context in your kubeconfig?

You can check this with `kubectl config get-contexts`.

If necessary change your context to Docker Desktop Kubernetes using `kubectl config use-context docker-desktop`.

Is it possible that you may have tried [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/) and this has left cluster/context in your `.kube\config`?

[Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Answer (score 0):

go to your HOME/.kube directory and check the config file. There is a possibility that the server mentioned there is old or not reachable.

you can copy the new config file(from remote server of the other directory of tools like k3s) and add/replace it in your HOME/.kube / config file.

Answer (score -2):

Same error message may also happen when you switch from local k8s cluster to a remote cluster that requires VPN to connect and you are not connected to VPN.